# How to add js and css files in ASP.net Core?

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been assigned to migrate an application from MVC into ASP.net Core, I'm new to ASP.net Core. In MVC we have `BundleConfig.cs` and in there we add references to our css and js files, how does it work in ASP.net Core? Let's say that I created a `test.js` and a `MyStyle.css` class, which is the best way to add references to it in every view? Should I place the `.js` and `.css` files inside `wwwroot/js` and `wwwroot/css`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I added the references inside the `_Layout` view, inside the `<environment>` tags:

```html
<environment names="Development">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/MyCss.css" />
</environment>
```

If anyone knows a better way I would welcome it

Comment: Do you know how it work for specific css view files ?

Comment: I think this answer is incomplete. For that to work, you need to place the `css` folder inside the `wwwroot` folder. Also, you need to add `app.UseStaticFiles()` in the `Configure` method in the `Startup` class.

Comment: What to location should you place your css files at?

Comment: @Shimmy Take a look into the wwwroot folder

Answer (score 11):

The better way to do it is to use: `app.UseStaticFiles();` inside  `startup.cs` before routing.

Comment: Can you explain the reason why this is better?

Comment: For more information see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 5):

In _layout:

```
@await RenderSectionAsync("Styles", required: false)
```

Then your view:

```
@section Styles{ your CSS }
```

Information from:
https://dev.to/amjadmh73/loading-custom-css-files-in-razor-pages-4no9

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27925327)

Comment: To expand on @lidermin's point, the question is about how to reference assets from _every_ view. Your answer seems to be answering a different question, something along the lines of "How do I allow views to inject styles into the `<head />` section?" Using your approach, however, the OP would have to repeat the script and style includes on every view.

Answer (score 4):

It might be a bit late to answer the question, but for the ones who come here via Google: I found that adding `asp-append-version="true"` worked for me, as all the other options given in the other answers were already provided in `_Layout.cshtml`.

Answer (score 2):

I put the JS and CSS files in an assets folder in the `wwwroot` folder of my application and then used link tags in my `_Layout.cshtml` to bring in the styles. Steven Sanderson has part a of a blog post where he talks about adding third party libraries [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/).

You could also do some sort of setup using webpack. I admit, this topic is not very straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I put the CSS files at `~/wwwroot/css`, and the JavaScript files at `~/wwwroot/js`.  Then I followed the format of the default _Layout.cshtml file.

```
<head>
   . . .
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/myCSS.min.css" />
   . . .
</head>

<body>
   . . .
   <script src="~/js/myJS.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

   @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
   . . .
</body>
```

Comment: this way it cant load the files in asp.net core mvc .

Answer (score 0):

Static files such as Image files, CSS files and JavaScript JS files does not work in ASP.Net Core unless it is placed in proper location with the project and also some settings are set.
And add this line in start up.css befor routing.

```
 app.UseStaticFiles();
```