# How to use Three.js in my ASP.Net Core web app

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, three.js

can anyone sugges me how to use Three.js in my asp.net core web api. How to make it when the user click on "3D" to open a html file with other js library and the 3d model. I write it on VS Code `https://pastebin.com/9dVZDxQt` and i dont know how to put it in my project

[the structure of asp.net web api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXSsf.jpg)

`[https://dox.abv.bg/download?id=93acbe4c25#]`[2](https://dox.abv.bg/download?id=93acbe4c25#) - The project

[java script folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Rav.jpg)

If anyone can explane me where to organize all the files and structure the code. Thank you of everyone

Comment: Normally, css and js libs are put into wwwroot > js. Then file how you normally would (on the page)

Comment: I dont know how exactly to use JS like API in .net Core

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839123/how-to-add-js-and-css-files-in-asp-net-core