# Include script or css file in view cshtml page in asp.net core 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to include script files and css files inside view cshtml but i am getting 404 error because it's trying to get the files from a different path.

```
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
  Layout = "_Layout_New";
}

@section Header{
  <script src="dist/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/main.css" />
}
<div>
  <div id="app"></div>
</div>
```

main.js and main.css are inside wwwroot folder.
when i checked the network calls this is how it's trying to fetch
request url https://localhost:44329/Controller/dist/main.js
but i think it should make a call like this to get the file https://localhost:44329/dist/main.js

When i am trying to include this in Home/Index it's working because that's the root.
Any ideas ?

Comment: i think you miss ``~`` in the path, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839123/how-to-add-js-and-css-files-in-asp-net-core) or microsof [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks @Sajid , adding ~ fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed the issue with help of @Sajid. The tilde character `~/` points to the web root, you can get more information from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-files-inside-of-web-root).