# Change color of the heart of Like with css on c# and ASP.Net Core

Tags: css, svg

I have vote(like) on my code on C# (ASP .NET Core)
Now I want , when I click on heart , the heart changes its color.
How do I do just with CSS (Not jQuery) with checking of If Condition
this is my Code on View :

```
 <div>

                                    <form method="post" asp-controller="Article" asp-action="AddArticleVote" asp-route-id="@article.Id">
                                        <button type="submit">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32.044" height="32" viewBox="  0 32.044 32">
                                                <path id="prefix__comment-heart" d="M18.016 12.16a4.912 4.912 0 0 0-5.664.848 4.8 4.8 0 0 0 0 6.784L16.88 24.4a1.6 1.6 0 0 0 2.272 0l4.528-4.528a4.8 4.8 0 0 0 0-6.784 4.912 4.912 0 0 0-5.664-.928zm3.392 5.376l-3.392 3.392-3.392-3.392a1.6 1.6 0 1 1 2.256-2.272 1.6 1.6 0 0 0 2.272 0 1.6 1.6 0 1 1 2.256 2.272zM18.016 2a16 16 0 0 0-16 16 15.823 15.823 0 0 0 3.617 10.127l-3.2 3.2A1.56 1.56 0 0 0 3.617 34h14.4a16 16 0 1 0 0-32zm0 28.8H7.473l1.488-1.488a1.6 1.6 0 0 0 0-2.256 12.8 12.8 0 1 1 9.055 3.744z" transform="translate(-1.972 -2)" style="fill: #ccc"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </button>
                                    </form>

                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target the `path` element and add [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) styles:

```
path#prefix__comment-heart:active {
    fill: blue;
}
```

For this to work remove the `style` attribute inline `fill` styles as this takes precedence over the fill styles shown above.

If you want to keep the greyish fill color you have now for when the button is not being clicked you can aditionally target `path#prefix__comment-heart` without the `:active` suffix.

Comment: I don't know how to write if condition. when I click on heart change color. I write my code on view that tell me how do I do?

Comment: I don't really understand, have you tried my answer? The active styles above will apply when you click on the heart button. My answer is the css-only approach, no if statements required.

Comment: Sorry I think You see just CSS with out if condition. but I don't understand yet. How do I do? can you write me correct code? I Hade to change style in CSS? or just on my codes?

Comment: Meaning of `:active` according to mdn: "The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button.". So this works on click. You can put this code in a .css file. [Relevant post for including styles in .net core applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839123/how-to-add-js-and-css-files-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: sorry for my initial questions. I am weak on CSS html :(. I found this code on another page that I get from Front Ended. I see he use this Code for some place for heart. straightly on view page.
you mean this code? But after click on it color of heart doesn't change. Have I change on code?

Comment: <style type="text/css">

                                            #comment-heart:hover #prefix__comment-heart {
                                                fill: #fa4b5a !important
                                            }

                                            #prefix__comment-heart {
                                                transition: all ease 0.6s;
                                            }
                                        </style>

Comment: @hasti.au In the example you shared your `svg` element doesn't have a `comment-heart` id. If the css selector doesn't match the styles won't be applied to the path. Either remove `#comment-heart:hover` and put the hover on `#prefix__comment-heart` or add the id to the svg element.

Comment: I change it to:
                                                 <svg id="comment-heart"   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32.044" height="32" viewBox="  0 32.044 32">
But now how can I tell it if was active( or click it its fill changes to: fill: #fa4b5a  (Red).

Comment: I write it on css file: 

#prefix__comment-heart {
    fill: #ccc !important;
}
#prefix__comment-heart:active {
    fill: #fa4b5a  
}

#prefix__comment-heart:active {
    transition: all ease 0.6s;
}
but doesnot work